# Convolving two complex signals - relationship between phase

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, phase

Suppose two continuous complex domain signals are convolved, how is the magnitude and phase of the resultant signal related to the magnitudes and phase of the original signals?

Comment: If you know that $z(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)y(t-\tau)d\tau$ then you also know what $|z(t)|$ and $\arg\{z(t)\}$ is. There is no 'simpler' expression for it in general.

Comment: So, without knowledge of the signals themselves, it is not possible to arrive at a generic relation between them?

Comment: If you take the magnitude and the phase of the convolution integral, then you have a generic relation, but of course you'll always have the integral.

Comment: Okay. That's exactly what I wanted to know - whether the integrals can be done away with or not. Thanks! I guess the question is closed.